# where is the .EXE?

Tags: vb.net

I have deployed an application using the "publish" procedure in Vb10. This application needs some configuration parameters that the user could modify, so I have put them in a .INI file that the application reads. The problem is that I need to put this .INI file in the same folder as the .EXE to let it work. Now I am not able to find where the .EXE is in the PC where I have installed the application (that is working properly, except that does not find the .INI).
Any help ?

Comment: Should be in the `bin` folder in your project dir.

Comment: yes, it is here in my PC where I developed it. But the question is where is on the PC where I will install !

Answer (score 1):

The best way to approach this is to have the .ini file deployed with your application.  This can be automated by changing a few properties in Visual Studio.

- Right click on the ini file and select Properties
- Set "Build Action" to "Content"
- Set "Copy To Output Directory" to "Copy Always"

Now when you publish the ini file will be copied along with it

[image]

Comment: thank you, this is the real hint I need, I will try it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

This will tell you the full pathname of the currently-executing assembly:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```